# Получить данные из формы в файл php

Tags: php

Мне надо вывести данные из формы в файл

Вот простая форма:

```
<form action="form.php" method="get"> 
<input type="text" placeholder=" Введите ваше имя"> 
<input type="text" placeholder=" Введите ваш возраст"> 
<input type="submit" value="Отправить"> 
</form>
```

Как сделать обработчик?

Comment: Надо вывести в файл result.txt

Comment: в form.php пиши if(isset($_GET['text'])){ $result=$_GET['text']; file_put_contents(1.txt, $result);}

Comment: И все????????????

Comment: ну либо метод пост выбираешь, либо гет соответственно $_POST или $_GET ну и запись в файл по строчно \r\n или PHP_EOL почитай в инете

Answer (score -3):

```
<form action="form.php" method="get"> 
 <input type="text" placeholder=" Введите ваше имя" name="name"> 
 <input type="text" placeholder=" Введите ваш возраст" name="age"> 
 <input type="submit" value="Отправить"> 
</form>

А в файле form.php добавить это в body:

<?php 
 $name = $_GET["name"];
 $age= $_GET["age"];
?>
```

Comment: Что-то я тут не вижу функций для записи $name и $age в файл + объяснили бы человеку зачем вы добавили атрибуты name в инпуты.